# What do i do if Selenium taking more time in case value is not present in dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to select values from a Drop down list,but in current build one list item is removed and in code i've mentioned removed list item name.While executing selenium script,it is taking more time,instead of any exception,below is my code.

```
WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("mySelect"));
Select dropdown= new Select(mySelectElement);
dropdown.selectByValue("HomeAdderess")
```

What should i do in this case?

Comment: Is there any other constraints/dependency of this _Test_? Ideally in current build if one list item is removed you need to skip the relevant _Test_.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think an implicit wait is set for a large amount( i.e 30,40 or 60 seconds).
   You can simply reduce the time by setting implicit wait.

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

It will only wait for 5 seconds.

2. Or you can skip the test as suggested above by DebanjanB.

Comment: same i did as per your suggestion but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different wait variable for these kind of tests. Or you can write a custom method to handle it verifyElementNotPresentOnDropdown()